# Is there a way to add a handler for copy event in WPF textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there a WPF equivalent of HTML's onCopy event for textbox control? I want to do some processing before the text is copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CommandManager.PreviewExecuted` routed event. This is raised when the Execute method on the RoutedCommand is called.

In the constructor:

```cs
CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(textBox, onPreviewExecuted);
```

Function:

```cs
private void onPreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the executed command is a copy command
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy)
    {
        // Custom processing here
        // ...

        // Mark the event as handled to prevent the default copy operation
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```